# How to extract text between <a> hyperlink tag

Tags: java, jsoup

Im trying to get text between an `<a>` tag but it doesnt want to work but it does work for `<strong>` tags

Code:

Example with a tag not working

```
public static void init() throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException{

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=example").timeout(20*1000).get();
    Elements taglink=doc.select("#rso > div.srg > li:nth-child(1) > div > h3 > a"); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(taglink.text());
    System.out.println("Text "+sb);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of the document. And the one that works.

Comment: If it works for ``strong`` tags, it should work for ``a`` tags, the parser doesnt make a difference. Check your document for the existence of an ``a`` tag as a neighbor of ``strong``.
EDIT: please show us the document and the real code. Line 1 is clearly broken and the selector is not the one you use in the code.

Comment: @weston hey man is that better?

Comment: Not really you need an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

 Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
```

}

You can try this code to get all the hyperlink as well as the text between the hyperlinks.Try this and let me know if you find any further problem.